# Excel crashes without errors or indication why when running simple VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

Excel has started crashing without any explanation and the code has worked previously so I am not exactly sure why it is constantly crashing now. It isn't even that much code or very complex. I am simply adding new values to a table in two separate worksheets. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sheet 1:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim nameStr As String
nameStr = TextBox1.Value
Dim costInt As Integer
costInt = TextBox2.Value

Dim newRateValues(8)
newRateValues(0) = nameStr
newRateValues(1) = costInt
newRateValues(2) = costInt
newRateValues(3) = costInt
newRateValues(4) = costInt
newRateValues(5) = costInt
newRateValues(6) = costInt
newRateValues(7) = costInt
newRateValues(8) = costInt

AddDataRow "ratesTable", newRateValues

AddDataRow2 "tableResources"
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, values() As Variant)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                table.ListRows.Add
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
    Else
        table.ListRows.Add
    End If

    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the entries from values()
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count).Range
    For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.count
        If col <= UBound(values) + 1 Then lastRow.Cells(1, col) = values(col - 1)
    Next col
End Sub

Sub AddDataRow2(tableName As String)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Dim newRate As Integer

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    newRate = ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                table.ListRows.Add
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
    Else
        table.ListRows.Add
    End If

    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the entries from values()
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.count).Range
    lastRow.Cells(1, 2) = newRate 
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the code line by line and see if it freezes or errors

Comment: Yeah it seems to dislike the `table.ListRows.Add` line

Comment: And what does it not like about it? hover above the line whilst stepping through. Is it throwing an error? If so what is the error

Comment: Doesn't specify, Excel crashes entirely right after that line, no information and no option to hover over any tooltip

Comment: Perhaps there is an infinite interation occuring somehow. Before that, first try setting screenupdating, enableevents to false and calculation to Manual.